Zero-Inflated Dirichlet
I want to set up a model that will rely on something similar to a zero-inflated Dirichlet distribution. As such, I'm trying to figure out how a zero-inflated Dirichlet distribution is set up from the start.
The Dirichlet distribution exists as the normalization of a product of gamma RV's to the unit simplex.
$$
X \sim \prod_{\ell = 1}^d\mathcal{G}(x_{\ell}\mid\alpha_{\ell}, 1)
$$
Let $r = \lVert X\rVert_{1}$, $y_{\ell} = x_{\ell} / \lVert X \rVert_1$ for $\ell = 1$ to $d-1$, and $y_d = 1 - \sum_{\ell = 1}^{d-1}y_{\ell}$.  Then,
$$
(r,Y) \sim \prod_{\ell = 1}^d \mathcal{G}(ry_{\ell}\mid\alpha_{\ell}, 1)\times r^{d-1}
$$
$r^{d-1}$ comes from the determinant of the Jacobian of the transformation from $X$ to $r,Y$.  Then $f(Y) = \int_0^{\infty}f(r,Y)dr = \text{Dir}(Y\mid\alpha)$
I'm trying to figure out the above process in the presence of zero-inflation.
Something like
$$
x_{\ell}\mid\alpha_{\ell}, \pi_{\ell} \sim (1 - \pi_{\ell})\delta_{(0)} + \mathcal{G}(x_{\ell}\mid\alpha_{\ell}, 1)
$$
Or
$$
x_{\ell}\mid\alpha_{\ell},\nu_{\ell} \sim \mathcal{G}(x_{\ell}\mid\alpha_{\ell}, 1)^{\nu_{\ell}}\delta^{1 - \nu_{\ell}}
$$
Is there any literature describing how the zero-inflated Dirichlet distribution is created?  I want to be able to reduce it back to the component gammas for Bayesian analysis.

I would first attempt a mixture of a Dirac delta distribution located at zero with the Dirichlet.

So what I've described here is a mixture of dirac(0) and gamma.  what are you suggesting?  dirac is uni-dimensional...  unless you're suggesting a mixture of $\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}\binom{d}{k}$ different dirac delta distributions and dirichlets.

I'm not sure to get what a zero inflated means, since a Dirichlet distribution is defined on the simplex, and zero doesn't belong to the simplex.

is $(0,0.5, 0.5)$ not on $\mathbb{S}_1^2$?

Let's say then I wish to expand the Dirichlet distribution to allow point masses at 0 in at most all but 1 dimensions.

@Faydey I think you mean "sparse" dirichlet, not zero inflated.  That might give you more finds in the literature.  Zeroinflated usually refers to a high probability of the RV you measure to equal 0, not that many events have zero probability of occuring.  The latter is what sparsity is about

For my application, I'm using Dirichlet as an angular distribution, or for dealing with compositional data, rather than considering it a "probability of occurence."  In this application, it might be appropriate to add a small jitter to observations so that they're not numerically zero, but if there's enough of them (and in this application, there's a lot of zeros), it messes with estimation of parameters.  I need a more nuanced approach.  I'll look into "sparse dirichlet".
